# Automatically pointing contract address to solidity interface

Tags: ethereum, remix, ether

I'm trying to use a interface on remix IDE and my only issue is that I have to copy and paste the contract's address.
Is there a way that I can point it automatically?

ty.

Answer (score 0):

In Remix IDE, you need to copy and paste the newly deployed address manually.

With frameworks, such as [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/), you can retrieve the address of the deployed contract in the code and then pass it to the other contract.

In the example below, we're passing the address of `First` instance to `Second`'s constructor, using the Hardhat JS framework.

```
const firstFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("First");
const first = await firstFactory.deploy();
await first.deployed();

const secondFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Second");
const second = await secondFactory.deploy(first.address);
await second.deployed();
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract First {}

contract Second {
    constructor(address firstAddress) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I'm trying to learn how to turn all my contracts into automatic contracts. I will try that on hardhat!